# Python or Ruby Interpreter on iOS

Tags: iphone, python, ruby, ios, lua

I found this application on the app store: [iLuaBox](http://www.mobileappsystems.com/software/iluabox)
and I wondered if there was anything else like this for the iPhone without jailbreaking but instead for Python or Ruby?

Lua is probably similar for me to play around with the basic programming I do anyway but I thought I would just ask)

Answer (score 18):

A python interpreter App called ***[Python for iOS](http://pythonforios.com/)*** is available on the App store:

*http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/python-for-ios/id485729872?mt=8&uo=4*

---

***Full disclosure:*** I am the sole creator/developer of the ***[Python for iOS](http://pythonforios.com/)*** App.

Comment: Looks good, I think I will buy this. Can you explain how you exchange source code with the desktop? iCloud support would be best, but can you at least use mail or something to get source to/from the device?

Comment: At the moment, Apple prohibits any kind of file syncing for Apps that run code or interpreters, but you can copy/paste from a website or an email.  And you can export viaemail as well.

Comment: @chown I'm building a coding interview app in iOS. I want to include python as a language choice for answer submission. How do I go about building something that is able to run python scripts?

Comment: Banner at the top in the App Store says it needs to be updated for IOS 11, does that mean it doesn’t work, or is just slow under 11/12?

Answer (score 9):

The Agreement about Apple not accepting any coding language layer has been removed not too long ago.

I guess we will have to wait a little to see complex language like Python and Ruby interpreter.

Since Lua is a scripting language, it is easier to port it.

Answer (score 9):

Pythonista by omz:software (I have no affiliation) just came out for the iPad and it looks pretty good. Has an extended keyboard, code completion and other nice things.

http://omz-software.com/pythonista/

App Store link: http://itunes.apple.com/app/id528579881

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to be able to run ruby and python scripts, codetogo lets you do that.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8

It gets around it by sending your code to a server, running it and then sending back the result.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a statically compiled Ruby variant for iOS:
http://www.rubymotion.com/

This has been built on top of the well established MacRuby framework.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking for (although the OP has not been back to SO for months so I doubt we can get any clarification).  I believe he wants to run Python/Ruby code directly in an App.  RubyMotion is a tool that allows you to write iOS Apps in Ruby instead of Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple native Python interpreter for IOS available now. No jailbreak needed:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pypad/id428928902?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

there is also python math which is free but it has its modules restricted to the math stuff but it allows you to sync .py scripts from itunes so you could import any modules that you need

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple forced them to remove the ability to sync .py scripts to/from the App/iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

http://pythonforios.com/

Try the above mentioned app. Not for free, but I guess it will do the trick

Answer (score -1):

A Python module that allows running Lua code from Python in a sandbox. Intended to execute arbitrary, possibly unsafe code submitted by users.

#### [Source code](https://github.com/mbr/luabox)