# Python for ios interpreter

Tags: python, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python or Ruby Interpreter on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772591/python-or-ruby-interpreter-on-ios)

I just discovered this apps [pypad](http://users.on.net/~jon.dowdall/pypad/index.html) and [python for ios](http://pythonforios.com/)

They have like an interpreter an editor

So which app would you recomend

But most importantly, how does this interpreter work, and where can i see an example of how the obj c and python get to work togheter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the sole creator of [Python for iOS](http://pythonforios.com) so that is of course what I would recommend, but a good indicator for your personal decision is the reviews & ratings of each App.  It took me weeks to figure out how to properly integrate python into Objective-c for this App but here is the best  resource to get you started (keep in mind that ObjC is just a superset of C):

http://docs.python.org/c-api/

---

Also, here is an example of calling a function defined in `myModule`.  The equivient python would be:

```
import myModule
pValue = myModule.doSomething()
print pValue
```

In Objective-c:

```
#include <Python.h>

- (void)example {

    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
    NSString *nsString;

    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Build the name object
    pName = PyString_FromString("myModule");

    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "doSomething");

    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
        if (pValue != NULL) {
            if (PyObject_IsInstance(pValue, (PyObject *)&PyUnicode_Type)) {
                    nsString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:((PyUnicodeObject *)pValue)->str length:((PyUnicodeObject *) pValue)->length];
            } else if (PyObject_IsInstance(pValue, (PyObject *)&PyBytes_Type)) {
                    nsString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:((PyBytesObject *)pValue)->ob_sval];
            } else {
                    /* Handle a return value that is neither a PyUnicode_Type nor a PyBytes_Type */
            }
            Py_XDECREF(pValue);
        } else {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
    } else {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    // Clean up
    Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    Py_XDECREF(pName);

    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    NSLog(@"%@", nsString);
}
```

For much more documentation check out: [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/)

Comment: HI man thanks a lot, I got the Python for iOS app, and am loving it, but i have a question what is the reference to the git hub link with the hidden functionality?, thanks a lot!, awesome job!

Comment: https://github.com/pudquick/PythonForiOSPatches The missing builtin modules what does this do? Ho to install? Thanks

Comment: Ah, this was stuff that a user created for v1.1 but I implemented in v1.2.

Comment: Thanks, this helps to interface python and obj-c. But how do you actually embed the interpreter in xcode? Is it a dylib? If yes, where do you got it from?

Comment: @bijan That was the tricky part.  It is built directly from the python source files which I modified specifically for this App (It took a lot of trial and error).

Comment: Hi, so are you saying that the Python source files are actually C files, and their API is in C thus allowing any interpreter to be built in a C-based language that can use Python's functionality? I have started to use Python for the first time and am entirely new to the concept of an "interpreted" language and am also confused about what is actually going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns That is exactly right.  All Python source is in C (a few module sources are in Objective-C, fortran, etc depending on the module).

Answer (score 10):

I recently wrote a small library, ObjP, to help embed Python in Objective-C apps. I wrote an article about that at:

http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/embedding-python-in-objc.htm

Comment: Has it been tested with (a recent) iOS?